# Divs side by side with same height and vertical line between them

Tags: html, css

I would like to achieve side by side, same height divs (without using table layout) and a single vertical line between them. I tried with flex container per row, but is unplesent to have the vertical line in many pieces...What can be the best solution for this problem?
I would like to have something like in the image bellow:
[image]

A sumary of what I tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.flex-container{
 display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */  
 display: flex; /* Standard syntax */
}
.flex-container .column{
    background: #dbdfe5;
    width: 100px;
}
.vr {
 background: red;
    width: 2px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="column">R1 - Col1</div>
        <div class="vr"></div>
        <div class="column bg-alt">R1 - Col2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="column">R2 - Col1</div>
        <div class="vr"></div>
        <div class="column bg-alt">R1 - Col2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:**  Rows number is N and the column content is dynamic, the height of the row should be dictated by the column which has much content in that row. (No JavaScript allowed!)
Thank you!

Comment: What have you done so far (apart from the sketch)?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Using the `flex-direction: column;` should be a way to go ;)

Comment: Please add the code you're using to the question.

Comment: is javascript allowed?

Comment: @R.Pülsinger JavaScript isn't necessary...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution with flexible height

using a wrapper to achieve the divider without interruption.

```css
.col-item {
  width: 49%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-item:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.col-item:nth-last-child(2),
.col-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
  <div class="col-item">
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  </div>
  <div class="col-item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!
  </div>
  <div class="col-item">
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The extra wrappers are an unnecessary addition

Comment: How is it different from `main` in your answer?

Comment: Sorry when I said wrappers, I meant the `.row` containers :)

Comment: Shows how much I was paying attention though to not realise you'd put the pseudo on the parent. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was able to remove the `.row`s.

Comment: this seams the best solution up to now, I'm wondering if is it compatible to IE 9 ?

Comment: No. Only [partial support in IE 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) with prefix `-ms-`

Comment: @V.Sambor You shouldn't need to support anything less than IE11 now since [Microsoft no longer support them either](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @fauxserious's answer, but you don't need to worry about multiple children in the column's because you add the pseudo selector to the parent container:

```css
main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

main>* {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20px; /* Same as margin */
  bottom: 20px; /* Same as margin */
  border-left: 1px solid #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a container for two column children, float those children to they are next to each other. Make a pseudo element and position it absolutely to make the line that separates the columns.

```css
main{
  height:500px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

main > *{
  float:left;
  width:46%;
  margin:2%;
  border:1px solid;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}

main > :last-child:before{
  content:"";
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:-4%;
  margin-left:-3px;
  top:0;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: how do you add multiple rows with the same vertical line?

Comment: Considering your edit, it sounds like flexbox (or potentially the new grid spec) would work better to ensure that the rows and columns match equally (if you are against tables).

Comment: @V.Sambor I've expanded this (good) answer so that you don't need to worry about multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

I did create an example aswell.

Maybe you like it.

```css
.content-left {
  width: 40%;
  height: 500px;
  border-right: solid 2px red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-right {
  width: 40%;
  height 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.left1 {
  height: 190px;
}

.left2 {
  height: 90px;
}

.left3 {
  height: 190px;
}

.right1 {
  height: 190px;
}

.right2 {
  height: 90px;
}

.right3 {
  height: 90px;
}

.right4 {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-left">
  <div class="content left1"></div>
  <div class="content left2"></div>
  <div class="content left3"></div>
</div>
<div class="content-right">
  <div class="content right1"></div>
  <div class="content right2"></div>
  <div class="content right3"></div>
  <div class="content right4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what if I have 1000 elements should I create a class for each in order to specify the height? imagine my content and number of rows is dynamic.

Comment: My solution is definitfly not supposed to be dynamic, but I didn't read "dynamic" in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to create a vertical line between two container and maintain the line from top to end

```css
.table_container.row{
       /* border: 0.5px solid #333;*/
        margin-top: -1px;
        display: flex;
     
    }
    .table_container .left_col{
       border-right:3px solid red;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="row table_container">
          <div class="col-md-4 left_col">Lorem</div>
          <div class="col-md-8 right_col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like that ? :

```css
header, section, .sub_section, footer {
  float:left;
  width: 40%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin-left: 6%;
}
header {
  height: 20vh;
}
section {
  height: 40vh;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.sub_section {
  height: 20vh;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
footer {
  height: 20vh;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<header></header>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<div class="sub_section"></div>
<div class="sub_section"></div>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: What about the line?